# What is the actual difference in the following statements

Tags: grammaticality, differences, non-native-english

> - Sentence 1:
>     Many Hindus study Sanskrit,but only *a* few Parsees study Avesta.
> - Sentence 2:
>     Many Hindus study Sanskrit,but only few Parsees study Avesta.

I fail to understand the difference between both the sentences,if any?
Which sentence is grammatically correct and should be used.

Comment: Your second sentence is not one that would appear in Standard English. “But only few” is virtually non-existent; it sounds wrong. You should remove *only* from the second sentence.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Ivean. Please, take a look to English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com), the new StackExchange proposal dedicate to those who are learning English as second language. Thank you.

Comment: No, though that thread is complementary. The limiting modifiers _only, merely_, and _just_ need 'a' when used before few. _But_ can take few or a few, but is old-fashioned in these usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, you are right that  limiting modifiers aren't covered in the other question.  However, I had already voted to close this question as a duplicate before I read your comment.  They should be merged.

Comment: What @Edwin said. The linked question involves *few/a few* as alternative ***objects*** (I have [a] few things). Both forms there are perfectly valid, and usually have different meanings. In this case we're talking about *[a] few **subjects***, where there doesn't seem to be any scope for different meanings.

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with grammatical rules. Idiomatically, we usually add the indefinite article if we're going to use *only* before *few*, but that's not a hard-and-fast rule. From Google Books:

> [but only few are](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20only%20few%20are%22&oq=%22but%20only%20few%20are%22&gs_l=serp.3...32116.42544.7.42967.15.15.0.0.0.0.81.686.15.15.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.FSBUFIi4OrM&pbx=1&biw=1296&bih=859&cad=cbv&sei=3wo9UeTBE8WJ7Aa9loH4Ag#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20only%20few%20are%22&oq=%22but%20only%20few%20are%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.4.24311.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..5.serp.24_aQcJS1e8&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 7,310 hits
>    [but only a few are](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20only%20few%20are%22&oq=%22but%20only%20few%20are%22&gs_l=serp.3...32116.42544.7.42967.15.15.0.0.0.0.81.686.15.15.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.FSBUFIi4OrM&pbx=1&biw=1296&bih=859&cad=cbv&sei=3wo9UeTBE8WJ7Aa9loH4Ag#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20only%20a%20few%20are%22&oq=%22but%20only%20a%20few%20are%22&gs_l=serp.3...3479.3765.1.4084.2.2.0.0.0.0.50.90.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.sGLiKjexY20&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 176,000 hits

I can't see any difference in meaning - with or without the article, with or without the word *only*, it nets down to the same thing. But it's worth pointing out that if we discard *only* and focus on the verb *to be*, the preference is *not* to include the article:

> [but few are](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20only%20few%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20few%20are%22&oq=%22but%20few%20are%22&gs_l=serp.3...4416.4712.4.5005.2.2.0.0.0.0.56.111.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.movxl33OYrE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 2,280,000 hits
>    [but a few are](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20only%20few%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20a%20few%20are%22&oq=%22but%20a%20few%20are%22&gs_l=serp.3...54264.55005.3.55644.4.4.0.0.0.0.46.152.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.mzRwCvX5AkE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 905,000 hits

I've no evidence to back me up, but I suspect the modern trend is probably moving towards including the article. The high number of hits for my example #3 are probably much influenced by long-established forms such as [many are called but few are chosen](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20only%20few%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22many%20are%20called%20but%20few%20are%20chosen%22&oq=%22many%20are%20called%20but%20few%20are%20chosen%22&gs_l=serp.3...436871.445948.5.446299.25.23.2.0.0.1.122.1348.22j1.23.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.xZ_rW54TCrw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859).

Comment: The first comparison doesn't distinguish between pronoun and quantifier usages of _few_ / _a few_.

Comment: @Edwin: I don't see it makes a lot of difference (my main point was that it's including *only* that makes the article much more likely), but I'll stick the verb in there too.

Answer (score 1):

It is more elegant to say the following:

> A. Many Hindus study Sanskrit; few Parsees study Avesta.  OR
>
> B. Whereas many Hindus study Sanskrit, few Parsees study Avesta.